# H5PY installed, but does not import

Tags: python-2.7, h5py, python-venv

I am trying to import H5PY in my Python code, but the module cannot be found. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7.

I have tried reinstalling h5py both with conda and with pip and individually and the following 
    sudo pip install cython
    sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
    sudo pip install h5py
but it still does not work.

Installing h5py tells me that it is already installed in /anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/128/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named h5py
```

Has anyone fixed this problem?

Comment: How do you install? If you install for example with `pip` you must make sure that it matches the installation of Python with which you are using to run your script.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution!

I added found out the path where h5py is installed and added it to the path where python looks for the modules with

```
import sys
sys.path.append("mypath")
```

Hope this also helps others

Answer (score -1):

For me the following worked:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-h5py
```

Ref: https://www.devmanuals.net/install/ubuntu/ubuntu-16-04-LTS-Xenial-Xerus/how-to-install-python3-h5py.html